# How to remove empty objects and array from JSON?

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [
        {
            "date": "xyz",
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
                "branch": [
                    {
                        "SHA1": "5213affe970c86cd6e13b9d0e52515ac53f46aae",
                        "name": "feature/demo"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {
            "date": "abc",
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
                "branch": [
                    {
                        "SHA1": "ca7972a32cc28304c22c98ceabf8e349fbf1a100",
                        "name": "refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.displayurlapi.actions.RunDisplayAction"
    },
    {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.RestartDeclarativePipelineAction"
    },
    {},
    {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.views.FlowGraphAction"
    },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {
      "_class": "org.marvelution.jji.export.ParentAction"
    }
    ]
}
```

JSON Object is too long for Jenkins multibranch pipeline so I have shared a few limited objects from JSON.

I need results like the below after excluding below listed Challenges:

`Name: refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz, SHA1: ca7972a32cc28304c22c98ceabf8e349fbf1a100`

Above result, I get using the below code but for that, I have removed blank object and other objects which don't contain **lastBuiltRevision**

```
import JSON

with open('jenkinsBuild.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

branch_name="refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz"

for actions in data['actions']:
    for branch_data in actions['lastBuiltRevision']['branch']:
        if branch_data['name'] == branch_name:
            print(f"Name: {branch_data['name']}, SHA1: {branch_data['SHA1']}")
```

Challenges:

1. If an empty object is there in JSON how to ignore that?
2. If JSON object doesn't contain ***lastBuiltRevision*** then how to ignore that object?
3. If JSON contains an empty array then how to ignore that?

Comment: can you explain the code `import JSON` ?

Comment: How would you remove them if the data *didn't* come from JSON? Once it's been loaded, it's the same as any nested dict/list structure that you'd create *in any other way*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below

```
data = {
  "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
  "actions": [
    {
      "date": "xyz",
      "lastBuiltRevision": {
        "branch": [
          {
            "SHA1": "5213affe970c86cd6e13b9d0e52515ac53f46aae",
            "name": "feature/demo"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      "date": "abc",
      "lastBuiltRevision": {
        "branch": [
          {
            "SHA1": "ca7972a32cc28304c22c98ceabf8e349fbf1a100",
            "name": "refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.displayurlapi.actions.RunDisplayAction"
    },
    {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.RestartDeclarativePipelineAction"
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.views.FlowGraphAction"
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      
    },
    {
      "_class": "org.marvelution.jji.export.ParentAction"
    }
  ]
}
branch_name="refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz"
data['actions'] = [x for x in data['actions'] if x and 'lastBuiltRevision' in x and x['lastBuiltRevision']['branch'][0]['name'] == branch_name]
for x in data.get('actions'):
  entry = x['lastBuiltRevision']['branch'][0]
  print(f'Name: {entry["name"]}, SHA1: {entry["SHA1"]}')
```

output

```
Name: refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz, SHA1: ca7972a32cc28304c22c98ceabf8e349fbf1a100
```

Comment: I need output for a specific branch which I pass as branch_name variable in question.

Comment: @Jayveer code was modified.

Comment: code modified but the output was not as expected.
I have mentioned what I need in the final output.

Comment: @Jayveer another code update was done.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely okay, much better than example in answer you accepted. There're two ways to deal with such as cases: prevent exception or handle exception.

**1. Prevent exception:**

```py
import json

with open('jenkinsBuild.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

branch_name = 'refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz'

for actions in data['actions']:
    if 'lastBuiltRevision' in branch_data:  # empty dict doesn't have this key too
        for branch_data in actions['lastBuiltRevision']['branch']:
            if branch_data['name'] == branch_name:
                print('Name:', branch_data['name'], 'SHA1:', branch_data['SHA1'])
```

**2. Handle exception:**

```py
import json

with open('jenkinsBuild.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

branch_name = 'refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz'

for actions in data['actions']:
    try:
        for branch_data in actions['lastBuiltRevision']['branch']:
            if branch_data['name'] == branch_name:
                print('Name:', branch_data['name'], 'SHA1:', branch_data['SHA1'])
    except KeyError:  # if any of accessed keys doesn't exist
        pass
```